# How can I count the number of records in a query that returns a very large dataset?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that hits several tables and will return a large number of records.  However, I can't just scroll to the bottom and get the line number to see how many records there are.  How can I have it just return the number of records in a one line result?

I tried putting it all in a 'FROM' statement but that only errored...UPDATE Because the ";" was *inside* the last ")"...GAH!!!.

```
select T1.col-1, T1.col-2, T1.col-3, sum(T1.col-4), sum(T2.col-1), T2.col-2
from T1, T2
where T1.inedx-1=T2.inedx-1
group by T1.col-1, T1.col-2, T1.col-3, T2.col-2
order by T2.col-2
```

Comment: Why would do you want to know how many records to show before they are shown?

Comment: @ik_zelf  because I can't 'show' 1.5 million records; I'm needing to know how many I would have with this solution before I start requesting tables and BI infrastructure to be built.  Can't very well ask 'em to build it and then try and insert 78,000,000 records the first time we populate the tables can I?  well I could but I'm pretty sure I would meet with a rather ugly and messy end 80D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from (

    select T1.col-1, T1.col-2, T1.col-3, sum(T1.col-4), sum(T2.col-1), T2.col-2
    from T1, T2
    where T1.inedx-1=T2.inedx-1
    group by T1.col-1, T1.col-2, T1.col-3, T2.col-2
    order by T2.col-2

)
```

Alternatively, I think the explain plan includes estimated rows:

```
explain select T1.col-1, T1.col-2, T1.col-3, sum(T1.col-4), sum(T2.col-1), T2.col-2
from T1, T2
where T1.inedx-1=T2.inedx-1
group by T1.col-1, T1.col-2, T1.col-3, T2.col-2
order by T2.col-2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you   put a `SELECT COUNT(*)` around your query it will return the number of records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT T1.col - 1, T1.col - 2, T1.col - 3, sum(T1.col - 4), sum(T2.col - 1), T2.col - 2
  FROM T1, T2
  WHERE T1.inedx - 1 = T2.inedx - 1
  GROUP BY T1.col - 1, T1.col - 2, T1.col - 3, T2.col - 2
  ) a
```

You don't need the `ORDER BY` for the `COUNT`.